# `replace` didn't work properly for dataframe

Tags: pandas

```
Twitter_Archive.iloc[:,13:].replace({'None':np.nan},inplace=True)
Twitter_Archive.iloc[:,13:].info()
```

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2356 entries, 0 to 2355
Data columns (total 4 columns):
 #   Column   Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------   --------------  ----- 
 0   doggo    2356 non-null   object
 1   floofer  2356 non-null   object
 2   pupper   2356 non-null   object
 3   puppo    2356 non-null   object
dtypes: object(4)
memory usage: 73.8+ KB
```

what's wrong with my code, I tried to replace 'None' string with `NaN` but it didn't work.

Comment: Do you have example input / output to reproduce this?

Comment: `Twitter_Archive.iloc[:,13:].astype(str).replace({'None':np.nan},inplace=True)`?

Comment: Are the `None` actually a string or are they `None` object?

Comment: >  `Twitter_Archive.iloc[:,13:].astype(str).replace({'None':np.nan},inplace=True)`? 

@MrNobody33 didn't work.

Comment: > Are the `None` actually a string or are they `None` object?

this is what the `type` python function shows me, it detects `None` as `str` type
`type(Twitter_Archive.iloc[0,13])`